# custom waterline join table

Tags: node.js, sails.js, schema, waterline

have a language model which stores all available languages.
Language:

```
attributes: {
    language: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    combinations: {
        type: 'array'
    }
}
```

A resume model:

```
user: {
        model: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    language: {
        model:''
        required: false,
        through: 'resumelanguage'
    }
```

Now I need to link theses two together such that a resume can have a collection of languages, and this linking should have another attribute with it; say `rank`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want resume to have many languages you must add `collection` attribute to it's model.

```
// /models/Resume.js
attributes {

    // Other attributes here

    user: {
        model: 'user',
        required: true
    },
    languages: {
        collection:'language',
        via: 'resume'
    }
};
```

Now if you want a [One-to-Many](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many) relationship, Language model must have `model` attribute

```
// /models/Language.js
attributes: {
    language: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    combinations: {
        type: 'array'
    },
    resume : {
      model: 'resume'
    }
}
```

If you want a [Many-to-Many](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many) relationship, Language model must have `collection` attribute too

```
// /models/Language.js
attributes: {
    language: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    combinations: {
        type: 'array'
    },
    resumes : {
      collection: 'resume',
      via: 'languages'
    }
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

Or you can use One-to-Many relationship on the "link" table (eg: LanguageResume) with both tables. Then you can add other attributes to the "link" table

```
// /models/LanguageResume.js
attributes: {
    languages: {
      collection: 'language',
      via: 'resumes'
    },
    resumes : {
      collection: 'resume',
      via: 'languages'
    },

    rank: {
        type: 'integer'
    },

}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain what your code does and how it solves the problem.  Answers that teach are much more useful than code without explanation.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote something but it's not here anymore. What happened ?

Comment: you've missed a part of my question. about includes other attributes like rank to the "link". maybe like you can specify a join table?